# Safari Cross Mark Entity always coloured red

Tags: css, html, safari, cross-browser

If I open the below fiddle in Safari on all devices, the cross mark entity is always coloured red.

http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/bgmx2d74/

```
a {
    color: #333;    
}
a:before {
    content: '\274C';
    color: #333 !important;
}
```

Is there a way to set the colour on the cross mark entity in Safari?

Comment: Is that an emoji thing? How about to use `content:'\00D7';` instead?

Comment: @Pangloss Ahh an emoji thing, that would make sense :( Your suggestion would be my next step, however I would rather stick with the cross mark if there is a way to change the colour.

Comment: If it is emoji, it became to an image I guess, so no way to change color.

Comment: TL;DR The solution is to add `\FE0E` to the content. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgmx2d74/9/).