# Ascii check mark is always red in mobile

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile

I use ✔ aka `&#10004;` in a cross platform web app.

Problem is, I need it to be white.

This works fine as expected by setting `color:#fff;` in the element's css in all tested platforms except via an android mobile device - I've tried Chrome and the default browser "Internet".

Nothing I try seems to change the color, and even when I have other text in the element, the other text is white and the check mark is red.

[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xy0u4e7e/1/) reproduces the issue, as does viewing this page on my phone.

My device is a Samsung Galaxy S6 SM-G920I Android 5.1.1

Comment: Can you show some code? It doesn't happen on my Android devices with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xy0u4e7e/1/)...

Comment: your fiddle reproduces the issue for me. i'll post my device versions.

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 doesn't have the issue, and neither does my phone, a HTC One. Is your issue similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31271454/1016716 ?

Comment: Yes i think it's the same issue. ... is my phone being too clever and converting the character to an emoji image? If so that is very stupid!

Comment: The accepted answer is not the correct solution-- scroll down to see Buster C's answer. Basically there are two checkmark characters in unicode and one of them is problematic on mobile. Use ✓ instead (this is the correct character....[here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) is its page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your check icons `span` `id`'s and then use the `!important` attribute to force the `span`'s colour. If that doesn't work, you could skip the trouble completely and use an icon from Font Awesome.

Here's a Fiddle explaining what I mean:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CheapApples12/x1ffy1uv/2/)**

Comment: The `id important` doesn't seem to help but font awesome does .. thanks. I guess it's a choice between that or an image

Answer (score 5):

@Mr Lister is correct and the problem is that chrome 58 on Samsung Galaxy S6 Android 5.1.1 (and probably a few others) renders this unicode character as an emoji which cannot then be styled with CSS.

I had the same issue and found that the light tick U+2713 displays as a text character on this version of chrome so can be styled.

Comment: Do you see a difference between ✔︎
and
✔️?

Comment: This isn't Chrome specific, as it happens on Opera too.

Comment: Also in safari. Confirming that changing to ✓ solved the problem for me in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Heavy check mark is being displayed different for every platform.  See [https://emojipedia.org/heavy-check-mark](https://emojipedia.org/heavy-check-mark/).